# Should one value simpler code over performance when returning multiple values?

Tags: java, design, coding-style, coding-standards

I'm too often facing situations where I need to get several types of information from a method. I usually think long and hard to circumvent these situations but I'm thinking it's pointless work that I'm doing. My question: should I prefer to take a slight performance hit in these situations, like iterating over an array twice for example (resulting in slower but cleaner code) or try to return everything at once with an instance of a custom helper class?

Here's a case example for the sake of it

```
char[] arr = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'};
int count = 0;  // 'a' and 'b' count
String word= "";  // 'a's and 'b's glued together in their occurring order
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= arr[0].length; ++j) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 'a' || arr[i][j] == 'b') {
            ++count;
            word += Character.toString(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
// return both 'count' and 'word' inside a new object or iterate twice?
```

Comment: This would be a better question with both "clear" and "fast" examples.

Comment: While your question hasn't been closed, you might find [Why was my question closed as primarily opinion-based?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6491/) useful.

Comment: Side bit, it *always* pains me to see `someString += moreStuff;` in Java. I've got a blog post on that - [What goes on behind the scenes of += with String in Java](http://shagie.net/2014/08/17/what-goes-on-behind-the-scenes-of-with-string-in-java/)

Comment: Actually, it would be better with a "real world" example (not to mention one that actually compiles). Especially because, in this case, `count` is simply `word.length()`.

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks for the link, I didn't know Java made an extra SB as well when concatenating.

Comment: Have you compiled this?  It doesn't, you know.  Maybe you want to eliminate the `(for j...)` loop?  And you could just write `return new String(arr).replaceAll("[^ab]", "")`?

Comment: @MichaelT: I wonder why Java uses a `StringBuilder` when using `+` or `+=` to combine two strings?  Is there any case where `string1 + string2` would be handled more efficiently with a `StringBuilder` than with `String.valueOf(string1).concat(string2)`?  Even for four strings, I would think `string.valueOf(string1).concat(string2).concat(string.valueOf(string3).concat(string4))` would be better than using a `StringBuilder`.  Of course, a decent static `String.concat` method with overloads for two, three, four, and N arguments would be even better, but that would require library code.

Comment: @supercat String.concat() with multiple strings creates many short lived Strings. StringBuilder doesn't. StringBuilder also works cleanly with types other than Strings, avoiding the need to convert it to a String first. StringBuilder works correctly, though the general model of += and + for Java strings is often not ideal code.

Comment: @MichaelT: When combining more than four strings, `StringBuilder` is the way to go, but when the `+` operator is used to combine four or fewer, the number of excess object allocations to create the `StringBuilder` and then produce the result exceed the cost of temporary strings even when combining them pairwise.

Comment: @MichaelT: The expression `string.valueOf(s1).concat(s2)` will generate a new `String` and a new `char[]` in the normal case; if either `s1` or `s2` is empty, it will return the other.  As Java implements it, `s1+s2` will generate a StringBuilder, at least one char[]` as a backing store, as well as a new `String` and a `char[]` for its backing store.  In what way is Java's use of the intermediate `StringBuilder` not a 100% loss compared with using `concat` in the two-item case?

Comment: @supercat yes, the `String + String` would  be better compiled into a String.concat() call. I am not sure if that wold be the case for `String + Integer` which gets more complicated. Three and more would be better done with StringBuilder. Still, to me, the entire structure of `String + ...` is something I'd consider to be a wart in the Java design - especially when one examines how it gets compiled. The `+=` being an especially bad case because of how there are typically a cascade of them.

Comment: @MichaelT: IMHO, the biggest problem is with the requirement that all strings be stored the same way.  If `string` had been an abstract class (with an abstract method using a package-private type so as to restrict implementation to classes within the package), having different classes for strings of 0-4 characters (using a `long` as a backing store), 0-255 ASCII characters (use `byte[]`), 0-255 not-all-ASCII characters (use `char[]`), or things assembled from subranges of `char[]` and `byte[]` arrays, there would have been much less need for `StringBuilder`

Comment: @MichaelT: Efficiently supporting a backing store that used `byte[]` rather than `char[]` might require an efficient (JNI) method to pack and unpack characters to bytes, but the benefits of cutting the array size by 50% for many common usage scenarios would outweigh the cost of such code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Premature Optimization is the root of all evil.

As [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) said,

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

Regardless of language, write your code to be as clear as you can.  If looping twice really results in clearer code, go ahead and write that.  A descent compiler may refactor away the second loop, or the overhead may be bottlenecked by other areas of your program.  Unless your software is very widely used, it's likely that the time your successor spends trying to decipher a quick but complicated block of code will be more expensive than the fractionally increased runtime.

If, after testing, you find that a given program is running unacceptably slow, a refactor to the more complex means may be appropriate.  But these situations are often difficult to identify in advance, because of this uncertainty more than anything else, you should err on the side of clarity over "performance" whenever such are in contention.

Comment: I'm going ahead and accepting this one because of the "write first optimize later" principle you mentioned, and the Knuth quote. Sometimes I forget

Comment: I am surprised you brought out this old chestnut.  You didn't even write the whole quote (it does matter), nor did you factor in sensible design decisions that should be made at the very beginning, like choosing the correct data structures having the appropriate performance characteristics for your particular programming task.  That's not premature optimization; it's just sensible design.  Writing slow code because you don't know simple performance optimizations that may actually enhance readability is not avoiding premature optimization; it's just a lack of education.

Comment: The question is about priorities, not the entire design process.  (Although a specific question about "which is clearer, an object-method or multiple scalar-methods" would be interesting, as either Java or OOP specific.)

Comment: Then don't call it design.  Call it "I pick the right data structures because I know what I'm doing."  Call it "I write reasonably fast code from the beginning, because I know what I'm doing."  Knuth's quote was always directed at the folks who don't understand what the 3 percent is (the part of the quote that you omitted), not the folks who are building adequate performance into their programs *from the beginning,* without using overly obtuse techniques.

Comment: Got a link to the complete quote?  I can update to include the rest.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: -1, the example of the OP does not get "less readable" by using a custom helper class - that is IMHO a false premise. Telling the OP the Knuth cite in such a situation leads him completely in the wrong direction (as we can see from the fact he actually accepted this answer). And I am pretty sure there is currently *no* compiler which can "refactor away the second loop", as stated in this answer.

Answer (score 10):

The "premature optimisation is the root of all evil" thingy is nice and cute, but it is [often misinterpreted](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=1038) and should not be used as an excuse [to write poor code](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/09/06/the-premature-optimization-is-evil-myth/): if you can easily write code that obviously performs better, you should (for example by choosing the right data structure or avoiding to loop twice when one loop can do the job).

In the simple example you showed, you could create a class that handles the specific job. Something like:

```
class FindAGoodName {

    FindAGoodName(char[] array, char... retain letters) {
        //your loop here
    }

    int getCount() {}

    String getWord() {}

}
```

The code will be as readable (possibly more readable) and you only loop once. Everybody happy.

Comment: "but, there's a lot of overhead in making a whole new class!"  -- would say the novice upon hearing that premature optimization is overemphasized.  :)

Comment: Yes, there is no justification for writing what I call *deliberately inefficient code*. [long rant omitted]

Comment: Classes do not necessarily have a lot of overhead. The question was about Java, which currently handles creating lots of little objects like this one very well.

Comment: Knuth's aphorism is one of the many good ideas that have been turned into mindless dogma by a segment of the developer community. I feel that software development attracts people who can only think in terms of dichotomies, and that if X is good, then total X must be perfection.

Answer (score 9):

If the code change results in a...

1. *measurable* performance improvement that
2. satisfies a non-functional software requirement, and
3. you cannot satisfy the requirement using simpler code

...then make the code change.  Otherwise, you're almost always better off writing code that is easier to understand and more maintainable.

Comment: Okay, so just common sense :) I was kind of expecting that

Comment: @WienerBoat Firstly common sense is not so common. But IMO Robert is saying more than that. Those three criteria actually impose quite strong constraints on what code changes we should make.

Comment: @WienerBoat as andy said, this is a lot stronger than 'common sense'. Condition 1 cannot be satisfied without actual performance measurements, taken before and after. More than once I've looked at code and gone.. "that has to be a bottleneck' only to later have the profiler tell me that some other thing completely the other side of the codebase is masking it completely.